# Identifying source of reference mosaic dataset in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, raster, arcgis-10.5, mosaic-dataset

I want to check the source mosaic dataset for a reference mosaic dataset within Python.

Using:

```
arcpy.Describe(reference_mosaic).referenced
```

I can confirm that the reference mosaic is indeed a reference mosaic, however, the describe object does not expose the path to the source mosaic dataset as far as I can tell, even though this information is easily accessible in ArcMap:

[image]

Using:

```
arcpy.Describe(reference_mosaic).childrenNames
[u'AMD_test_reference_BND', u'AMD_test_reference_LOG', u'AMD_test_CCA', u'AMD_test_reference_DEF']
```

I can see that the reference mosaic has a child (AMD_test_CCA) that refers to the source mosaic, however, I cannot interact any further with this item as arcpy says that it does not exist. Although the name of this child does confirm the name of the source dataset, I would prefer to confirm the absolute path of the source dataset.

Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions as to how I could achieve this?

As the reference mosaic dataset has an image service being published from it, I will do not want to have to recreate the reference mosaic and go through the rigmarole of stopping and/or reconfiguring the service.

Using ArcGIS Desktop 10.5.1 on Windows 7 64-Bit.

Comment: Not every property is exposed to arcpy, you may need to use some ArcObjects in your arcpy to get the referenced dataset, perhaps IMosaicDataset.Catalog is what you're after http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#/IMosaicDataset_Interface/001q00000m8s000000/

Answer (score 1):

As commented by @MichaelStimson:

> Not every property is exposed to arcpy, you may need to use some
>   ArcObjects in your arcpy to get the referenced dataset, perhaps
>   IMosaicDataset.Catalog is what you're after
>   http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#/IMosaicDataset_Interface/001q00000m8s000000/